# MS SQL CONCAT vs "+" query difference (with Doctrine 2)

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine-orm

I am using the Doctrine 2 interface to access MS SQL database. I found the problem that is pretty interesting on both sides: Doctrine 2 and the MS SQL.

Doctrine 2 for some reason changing query

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from(table::class, 'il')
            ->select('CONCAT(il.col1,il.col2,il.col3) AS concated')
```

changing to something like (it is using own aliases):

```
SELECT (t0_.col1+ t0_.col2+ t0_.col3) AS sclr_0 FROM tableName t0_
```

The most important - it changing the `CONCAT` into expression with "+". But it works fine (or it looks like it does) till I would like to compare concated string to value in other table...

```
$targetQueryBuilder->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from($namespace, 's')
            ->select('1')
            ->where('CONCAT(il1.col1, il1.col2, il1.col3) = s.controlValue')
            ->andWhere('s.tableName = :tablename')
            ->andWhere('s.tableRowIdentifier='.$rowIdentifier);
```

(I am writting this query from memory, if there is a something wrong - it doesn't matter - it is to visualise the issue)
Executing raw query in SQL Studio works absolutely fine with `CONCAT` function. With "+" it doesn't. All concated columns having nvarchar type. The question is: Where is a difference?

I checked a huge amount of combinations in doctrine to skip mapping `CONCAT` into "+" but no success, I had to wrote some dummy lexer extension to force the `CONCAT` function to be applied to the final query.

Additional (maybe ms sql server specific) issue is:
When I was testing

```
SELECT
(i1_.NameUnternehmen + i1_.Land + i1_.Ort + i1_.Straße + i1_.Postleitzahl) AS a,
CONCAT(i1_.NameUnternehmen , i1_.Land , i1_.Ort , i1_.Straße , i1_.Postleitzahl) AS c
FROM tablename
```

(the `Straße` colum name looks like is not important in this issue)
When using the WHERE statement to compare concated string with the control value, a select result is different.

`->where('CONCAT(il1.col1, il1.col2, il1.col3) = s.controlValue')` - everything is correct

`->where('(il1.col1 + il1.col2 + il1.col3) = s.controlValue')` - result in column "a" is null. I just tested and on other tables it is not null sometimes. I don't know why. 
The "c" column is always correct.

Comment: Larnu explains the differences well. You could do `ISNULL(il1.col1, '') + ...` or `COALESCE(il1.col1, '') + ...` but eww. No idea why doctrine would change the query. Seems like a big bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CONCAT` and `+` don't operate the same. If any expression has the value `NULL` when using `+`, then `NULL` will be returned. For `CONCAT`, it will implicitly replace `NULL` with `''`, so `NULL` won't be returned.

`CONCAT` will also implicitly convert any values in the expression to an `(n)varchar`, where as `+` uses [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the datatype and implicitly converts other values in the expression to the data type of the highest precedence.

Examples:

```
SELECT c1,
       c2,
       c3,
       c4,
       c1 + c2 + c3 + c4, --NULL 
       CONCAT(c1, c2, c3, c4) --'abcdefxyc'
FROM (VALUES('abc','def',NULL,'xyz'))V(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

Implicit conversions:

```
SELECT c1 + c2 + c3 + c4
FROM (VALUES('abc','def',7,'xyz'))V(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abcdef' to data type int.

```
SELECT CONCAT(c1, c2, c3, c4) --'abcdef7xyz'
FROM (VALUES('abc','def',7,'xyz'))V(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

*Interesting but expected behaviours:*

```
SELECT c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 --NULL
FROM (VALUES('abc','def',NULL,7))V(c1, c2, c3, c4);

SELECT c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 --123456790
FROM (VALUES('123','456','789',1))V(c1, c2, c3, c4);
```

*The reason for this behaviour is because the expressions are evaluated left to right. For the first, you therefore have `'abc' + 'def' = 'abcdef'` then `'abcdef' + NULL = NULL` (`varchar`). Finally you have `NULL + 7 = NULL`, which is fine as `NULL` can be implicitly converted to an `int`.*

*For the latter, you have `'123' + '456' = '123456'` then `'123456' + '789' = '123456789'`. Finally you have `'123456789' + 1 = 123456789 + 1 = 123456790`. notice in the final expression the `varchar` is first implicitly cast to an `int`, and then the `+` operator acts as addition, rather than concatenation.*

Comment: Thanks! I never thinking about that option to change CONCAT to the "+", but PHP Doctrine 2 is changing all "CONCAT" to this "+". I waste a lot of time to find solution that will disable this replacement :(

Answer (score -2):

CONCAT and '+' both are different.
In mysql concat simple combine/join our data/sting/number.
Main different is datatype.